# Create 3 Tier Dictionary and Print from third level

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to create a 3 tier dictionary that will store MPLS circuit information. I tried just a 2 tier but made the discover that the information gets overwritten by the very last entry in the dictionary tier.

Once I have that dictionary i would like to be able to present to the user via the print statement the available carrier's within that dictionary.

Here is my dictionary Structure.

```
carriers = {
    '4': {
        'AT&T': {
            "Role":"Primary", "Interface":"TenGigabitEthernet4/3/0", "Location":"Computer Center"},
        'CentPri': {
            "Role":"Primary", "Interface":"GigabitEthernet4/0/0", "Location":"Computer Center"},
        'CentSec': {
            "Role":"Secondary", "Interface":"GigabitEthernet1/2/0", "Location":"ESF"},
        'Verizon': {
            "Role":"Primary", "Interface":"GigabitEthernet1/0/0", "Location":"ESF"}
        },
    '2': {
        "TeliaSonera": {
            "Role":"Primary", "Interface":"GigabitEthernet0/0/1", "Location":"Mannheim"},
        "Verizon": {
            "Role":"Primary", "Interface":"GigabitEthernet0/0/0.40", "Location":"Mannheim"},
        "AT&T": {
            "Role":"Primary", "Interface":"GigabitEthernet1/0/0.2", "Location":"Mannheim"}
        },
    '1': {
        'Tata': {
            "Role":"Primary", "Interface":"GigabitEthernet0/0/6", "Location":"TCI - 1, Pune, India"}
        }
            }
```

And here is where i ask the user for what region to pick and then ask what carrier they want to know about.

```
region_choice = raw_input("Select a Region: (1-4)\n")
if region_choice in carriers:
    carrier_choice = raw_input("Select from the following carriers: {}".format(carriers[region_choice][0]))
```

I realize i have a [0] after the carriers[region_choice] but that's where i'm stuck.

How can I display all of the Carriers from the dictionary selected?

Desired Result:

Select a Region: (1-4)
4

Select from the following carriers: AT&T, CentPri, CentSec, Verizon
AT&T

I can do the rest from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
region_choice = raw_input("Select a Region: (1-4)\n")
if region_choice in carriers:
    carrier_choice = raw_input("Select from the following carriers: {}".format(", ".join(carriers[region_choice].keys())))
```

Result:

```
Select a Region: (1-4)
4
Select from the following carriers: CentSec, AT&T, Verizon, CentPri
```

Basically you want the `keys` of your region `dict`. This returns a `list` which you can turn into a string via `join`.

Keep in mind, since dicts are unordered, you can't guarantee the order of carriers in the string. For that you'd need an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).